# CakePHP i18n not working

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, gettext

I followed the instruction and created .po file with PoEdit with Language: Vietnamese, Country: VIETNAM in:
my_app **./Locale/vie/LC_MESSAGES/default.po**

I double check it with a plain editor to see the msgid and here is an example:

#Path

msgid "Login"

msgstr "Đăng nhập"

In the bootstrap.php: **Configure::write('Config.language', 'vie');**
I tried **Configure::write('Config.language', 'vi');** also.

In the view file I echo __("Login"); but it still displays "Login"...

I have tried so many ways to make it work even restart Apache or my computer but no success. Any helps will be appreciated!

My ENV:

- XAMPP v1.7.3 with gettext lib enabled
- MAC OSX Lion 10.7.2
- CakePHP 2.1.1 Stable

Comment: You have the .po file, has it been compiled into a .mo file? That is the one used by php

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `uses ( 'L10n' );` in there?

A code sample would help. I know there's several files involved, but that's just the way things are.. samples from each file. Have you read through the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1230/Localization-in-CakePHP)?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529020/cakephp-localization) also speaks to file organization.

Comment: I used this in beforeFilter but no success:
  `App::import('I18n', 'L10n');
  $l10n =& new L10n();
  $l10n->get("vie");
  echo __("Login");`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that *.po files are OK, deleting the files inside the folders can help.
(Not folders, only files)

```
/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_*
```